# reset_password_sent_at assignment for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The issue is that devise is checking the reset_password_sent_at when a user clicks on the link to reset their password (from an email) and when trying to reset (in the form) an error occurs:

```
Reset password token has expired, please request a new one
```

Meaning, "when a reset_password_token is generated, @user.reset_password_sent_at needs to be set to Time.now, or else when devise runs @user.reset_password_period_valid? to find out if the reset token is still valid, it will get nil and assume the token has expired."

What I don't understand is how and where to assign reset_password_sent_at to Time.now

Do I need to assign Time.now through the console to all Users? If so, How would I do that?

Or, is it a before_create (or something else) that I need to assign Time.now to reset_password_sent_at? If so, how and where should I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to worry about `reset_password_sent_at`; that is something `devise` will take care of setting correctly when a reset_password is sent to the user.

`reset_password_sent_at` works in conjunction with the `reset_password_within` parameter, set in the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file. It should look something like this:

```
config.reset_password_within = 2.hours
```

Most likely it is set to `nil` or `0`, and that is making the application throw the `password reset token has expired` method.

Comment: Also watch out -- I had a column set as a `time` in Postgres instead of `timestamp` so it _always_ was invalid. Dropped the columns and recreated as `timestamp` and it worked beautifully.

Comment: I am also getting same error Reset password token has expired, please request a new one I have done the above changes which you mentioned but still I am getting same error.